# How to detect if touch is within a certain area

Tags: unity-game-engine

Try to detect if player's touch is inside the play area, and if so, start a timer. I already have the starting a timer part working for keyboard input, just not touch (mobile) input.

```
if(...) {
    timer.Start();
}
```

My game board is a Rect Transform with a sprite:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I tried what's in the duplicate but it still didn't work.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler 
{
    void Start() 
    {
        ...
        // For touch controls
        addPhysics2DRaycaster();
    }

    // For touch controls
    void addPhysics2DRaycaster()
    {
        Physics2DRaycaster physicsRaycaster = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Physics2DRaycaster>();
        if (physicsRaycaster == null)
        {
            Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<Physics2DRaycaster>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where I try to start the timer:

```
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    timer.Start();
}
```

Here is the code for the controls:

```
// FixedUpdate() - called before physics calculations
void FixedUpdate() {
    // Touch swipe input
    if(controlToggle.isOn) {
        joystick.SetActive(false);
        controlToggle.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Swipe";

        if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
            Touch myTouch = Input.touches[0];

        if(myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            touchOrigin = myTouch.position;
        } else if(myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && touchOrigin.x >= 0) {
            Vector2 touchEnd = myTouch.position;
            float x = touchEnd.x - touchOrigin.x;
            float y = touchEnd.y - touchOrigin.y;
            touchOrigin.x = -1;
            float moveHorizontal = x;
            float moveVertical = y;
            Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);
            rb2d.AddForce(movement * speed);
        }
    }
}

...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "certain area"? Want to detect click on a sprite?

Comment: Yes, the sprite is the game board area

Comment: Although its more of a swipe than a click if that makes a difference

Comment: Alright. See #7 from the duplicate since this is a 2D collider.

Comment: I followed it as best I could, but it still isn't working. Added the new code to the question @Programmer

Comment: Read the code again. You have to implement `IBeginDragHandler` if you want to use `OnBeginDrag`. Read it again.

Comment: I added it, but my timer still doesn't start when I do a drag anywhere on the screen

Comment: I also don't see where I reference the sprite I'm trying to target @Programmer

Comment: You tried something and it doesn't work? Update your question with your new code. By the way, you supposed to add "EDIT" then your new code so that your original code will be conflict with your Edit

Comment: Ok, I added the one class you talked about to my code `IBeginDragHandler`. And idk what you mean by add "EDIT", I don't understand your "english". @Programmer

Comment: I rolled it back for you and fixed the "EDIT" stuff I talked about. Now you should understand how to properly edit your question. Note that script in your question must be attached to the object you want to detect clicks on. Put `Debug.Log` inside the `OnBeginDrag` function and see if it gets called. Also, remove canvas from your sprite object. That is unnecessary.  Canvas is used for UI Objects not for Sprite Renderer.

Comment: Since my timer is attached to a different object than where I want to detect click, how do I access the timer from another controller? @Programmer